# Writing a script to rsync all directories

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, rsync

I have a huge set of backup files, each containing a directory of Videos.  Each video directory is slightly different.  I would like to merge these into a single directory to conserve, as I don't really care about which backup each Video came from.

To do this, I figure that rsync would be the best tool but I'm having difficulty coming up with a nice clean script to rsync each backup's Video directory with an outside destination.

In other words, I want a script that will automate the following process

```
rsync -a ./Backups/Backup-x/Videos/ ./CollectedVideos/
rsync -a ./Backups/Backup-y/Videos/ ./CollectedVideos/
rsync -a ./Backups/Backup-z/Videos/ ./CollectedVideos/
rsync -a ./Backups/Backup-t/Videos/ ./CollectedVideos/
```

Where all files in the `Backups/` directory are "fair game."

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at least one of the folders in `./Backups` contains a `Video` directory,

```
for dir in ./Backups/*/Videos
do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]
    then
        rsync -a $dir/* ./CollectedVideos/
    fi
done
```

might be close to what you are looking for.

The `/*` after `$dir` is important to copy the files without including their directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did using wildcards not work:?
 `rsync -a backup//Videos/ /` 
The other way is to use find and xargs:
`find backups/Backup-*/ -type f -name ""| xargs -I {} -n 1 rsync {} /` 
Of course, find is a very slow running command